# How to ensure ItemCheck occurs before calls inside the event method

Tags: c#, events, checklistbox

So the issue is quite simple really. I have a checkedListBox and on ItemCheck I want to call my Method UpdateGraph(). The problem is, if I call it in the event, it runs through the UpdateGraph method before the item is considered check. Since the update graph method uses a foreach (var item in checkListBox.CheckedItems)
its important that the new value of checked or not is already applied.

I tried a workaround by manually setting the new value in the event however, this gave me a StackOverflowException.

```
private void checkedListBox3_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
    {
        checkedListBox3.SetItemChecked(e.Index, true);
    }
    else
    {
        checkedListBox3.SetItemChecked(e.Index, false);
    }

    UpdateChart();
}
```

it gives me the exception on  the line where i SetItemChecked. 
Just to re-state, I want the item to be checked BEFORE UpdateChart(), and just calling UpdateChart() doesn't seem to do this. Does anyone have any workarounds to make the item checked before it goes into the UpdateChart() method?

EDIT: Thanks, I understand now why I was getting StackOverflowException now, however is there anyway to ensure the item takes on the new CheckState without manually passing it through to my UpdateGraph method? Its a bit of a universal method that wont always be going through my checkedListBox3_itemCheck event so passing in a newCheckstate could complicate things. Mind you I can just use an If to check my passed in value anduse an identifier of some sort to determine whether it needs to be used, but that will probably be my last solution if I cant find anything else to update the checkstate before going into the method.

Comment: You change check state and that fires ItemCheck so obviously you get a StackOverflow exception because you end up in an endless loop (item changed -> fires itemcheck -> changes item -> fires itemcheck etc.)

Comment: From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck(v=vs.110).aspx) `Remarks:
The check state is not updated until after the ItemCheck event occurs.`

Comment: If you read ItemCheck documentation => "The value is not updated until after the event occurs", so maybe you could pass the newValue as parameter to your updateChart function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the you pointed out there is no `OnItemChecked` event that happens after the value is set so you'll have to think of another way:

You could refactor your update method to something like `UpdateGraph(int? changedIndex = null, bool isChecked = false)` That way you can call it just as `UpdateGraph()` where you currently use it and then

```
private void checkedListBox3_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateGraph(e.Index, e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked);
}
```

After evaluating your `foreach` as normal you can then check for `changedIndex == null` and react accordingly.

Comment: Mind explaining exactly what the ? on "int?" does? I've only really used ? on  invoking events for checking if they exists. Does this do the same thing?

Comment: int? is a shortcut for Nullable<Int32>. I guess you could use `int changedIndex = -1` - basically you want a value that won't occur unless set by your other code

Comment: Ahh okay. Just to further my understanding, when you set a variable in the method definition, like how we are doing here, if a value is passed in it will use the passed in value instead of the "default" value we have set? in this case the "default" value for int? changedIndex == null right?